# Performance issue with Zxing library - Android

Tags: android, zxing

I have downloaded the ZXing source code from the following location:

- https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Using eclipse as the IDE ,  I imported the ZXing source code(CaptureActivity project) , which is itself an Android application . On its Build Path , I have checked it as IsLibrary.

Now , I have added the CaptureActivity project as a reference to my Android project.

The code has been integrated properly and is running.
I compared the performance of the Barcode scanner which is available on the Google Play and the build(apk) which I generated from the source code.

I found out that there is difference in the performance of the above two , the application downloaded from the Google Play has a much better performance(it is able to scan barcode a lot faster than the one which I generated from their source code.) and in few cases the application generated from their source code was unable to scan a barcode , which can be done from the application downloaded from Google Play.

Did anyone find such performance issues?

Any suggestions/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the device connected to a debugger at the time you are testing **your** application? It impacts the performance.

Comment: I have individually installed both the applications - one downloaded from Google Play and the other generated from the Zxing source code and not connected in debug mode

Comment: You could try it with different `Readers` and/or `Sources`. Else you could try it with [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).